# Social Paradigm

Tags: meaning, expressions, learning, books

It is come from the 7 habits of highly effective people book (2004) by Stephen Covey.

He have mentioned Character Ethic & Personality Ethic are the examples of social paradigms. (Page 23)

I understand what is paradigm from this book. But I can't really understand the meaning of the sentence above.

What I understand paradigm is the way we "see" things but not visually instead of how we interpret it. Character Ethic as the foundation of success. Personality Ethic two paths one was human and public relations techniques and other was positive mental attitude.

In new age, most of our paradigm was affected by personality ethic. Character ethic has been long forgotten since World War 1. This is the relation that I can see how character ethic and personality ethic related to paradigm.

I am confuse on how the character ethic & personality ethic will become the example of social paradigms and what is the meaning of social paradigms.

Thank you.

Comment: I don't believe you have quoted the above accurately.

Comment: I don't think your understanding of _paradigm_ is correct. A paradigm is a pattern or model.